# Select all rows that have column value larger than some value

Tags: mysql, sql, select

I have a SQL table thus:

```
username  |  rank 
a         |  0
b         |  2
c         |  5
d         |  4
e         |  5
f         |  7
g         |  1
h         |  12
```

I want to use a single select statement that returns all rows that have rank greater than the value of user e's rank.

Is this possible with a single statement?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes it is possible.

```
SELECT * FROM MyTable 
WHERE rank > (SELECT Rank FROM MyTable WHERE username = 'e')
```

or you can also use `self-join` for the same

```
SELECT t1.* FROM MyTable t1
  JOIN MyTable t2
    ON t1.Rank > t2.Rank
   AND t2.username = 'e';
```

#### See [this SQLFiddle](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!2/d9d07f/1)

Answer (score 2):

You can use subquery

```
SELECT * FROM `table` WHERE `rank` > (
SELECT `rank` FROM `table` WHERE `username` ='b' LIMIT 1)
```

Answer (score 2):

This is just an edit script of @UweB.. It will return the max rank even if there are multiple rows for username='e'

```
SELECT *
FROM tbl 
WHERE
tbl.rank > (
   SELECT max(rank) FROM tbl WHERE username = 'e')
```

Answer (score 1):

```
SELECT *
FROM tbl 
WHERE
   tbl.rank > (
       SELECT rank FROM tbl WHERE username = 'e'
   );
```

Note that this will only work if the sub-select (the part in brackets) returns a single value (one row, one column so to speak) only.